# Socket JAVA se cierra antes de enviar un ACK

Tags: socket, servidor

> Mi codigo para entender este es un socket servidor recibe un mensaje de "n" lineas con caracteres hexadecimales al inicio y final(protocolo MLLP), pero al ser analisado este buffer para pasar a string y pasarlo despues a mi procedure ocasiona que el socket se cierre y no puedo enviar el ack de  respuesta

public void run() {
    log.info("Empieza el hilo");
    PrintStream escritura; //Canal de escritura
    BufferedReader lectura; //Canal de Lectura
    String mensaje = "";
    int pase = 1;
    //StringBuffer messageHL7 = new StringBuffer();
    txtOutput.setText("Iniciando");
    try {
      //Creo el socket server
      log.info("Se inicia el socket en el puerto: " + port);
      txtOutput.append("\nSe inicia el socket en el puerto: " + port);
      server = new ServerSocket(port);
      /*Aqui empieza el bucle infinito hasta darle en stop*/
      while (true) {
        log.info("Empieza bucle");
        //Invoco el metodo accept del socket servidor, me devuelve una referencia al socket cliente
        if (pase == 1) {
          log.info("Escuchando conexiones entrantes");
          txtOutput.append("\nEscuchando conexiones entrantes");
        }
        socket = server.accept();
        //Obtengo una referencia a los canales de lectura y escritura del socket cliente
        lectura = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        escritura = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        //lectura del mensaje recibido
        /*--AQUI EL PROBLEMA: PASA A STRING EL BUFFER RECIBIDO PERO
        ----PROVOCA UN CIERRE DEL SOCKET Y NO PUEDO ENVIAR MI MENSAJE ACK--*/
        ScannerReaderNoNextTest srnnt = new ScannerReaderNoNextTest();
        mensaje = srnnt.inputStreamToString(socket.getInputStream());

```
    //imprime mensaje recibido
    System.out.println("Mensaje recibido: " + mensaje);
    txtOutput.append("\nMensaje recibido: " + mensaje);
    log.info("Mensaje recibido: " + mensaje);
    //mensaje es reemplazado por el ack para ser reenviado al emisor
    String msgack = pr.SET_MENSAJE_HL7(mensaje);
    //Escribo en canal de escritura el ack de confirmacion
    escritura.println(msgack);
    txtOutput.append("\nACK enviado: " + msgack);
    log.info("ACK enviado: " + msgack);
    escritura.close();
    lectura.close();
    socket.close();
    pase++;
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  log.error("No se pudo crear el socket");
} catch (Exception ex) {
  java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(HL72018_Recepcion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```

}